# How to check if checkbox was checked?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am creating a quiz app for androids. I have 3 fragments and 3 checkboxes on first two of them. On the last fragment there is a button which when pressed opens an activity called "End". I need that on the "End" activity a result would appear of how many correct answers one have chosen.

Firstly, I've tried to check if it's working with only the first fragment, but I got stuck. The app closes when I press the button.

**End.java**:

```
       package bandymas.viewpagerexample;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class End extends ActionBarActivity {

    private CheckBox checkBox1, checkBox2, checkBox3;
    private Button button;
    TextView newresult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_end);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    private void addListenerOnButton() {

        checkBox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        checkBox2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
        checkBox3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            //Run when button is clicked
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
                result.append("CheckBox1 : ").append(checkBox1.isChecked());
                result.append("\nCheckbox2 : ").append(checkBox2.isChecked());
                result.append("\nCheckBox3 :").append(checkBox3.isChecked());

                newresult.setText("My Awesome Text");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_naujas_baigimas, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Here's my **logcat**:

```
04-01 20:04:37.564    6020-6020/bandymas.viewpagerexample W/ApplicationPackageManager﹕ getCSCPackageItemText()
04-01 20:04:37.564    6020-6020/bandymas.viewpagerexample I/PersonaManager﹕ getPersonaService() name persona_policy
04-01 20:04:37.684    6020-6020/bandymas.viewpagerexample I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:381>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (CL3869936)
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 17.01.11.SPL
    Build Date: 01/17/14 Fri
    Local Branch:
    Remote Branch:
    Local Patches:
    Reconstruct Branch:
04-01 20:04:37.734    6020-6020/bandymas.viewpagerexample D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
04-01 20:07:31.404    7094-7094/bandymas.viewpagerexample I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_android_load_priority [0], There is no sepolicy file.
04-01 20:07:31.404    7094-7094/bandymas.viewpagerexample I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_android_load_priority , priority version is VE=SEPF_GT-I9505_4.4.2_0033
04-01 20:07:31.404    7094-7094/bandymas.viewpagerexample I/SELinux﹕ selinux_android_seapp_context_reload: seapp_contexts file is loaded from /seapp_contexts
04-01 20:07:31.404    7094-7094/bandymas.viewpagerexample E/dalvikvm﹕ >>>>> Normal User
04-01 20:07:31.404    7094-7094/bandymas.viewpagerexample E/dalvikvm﹕ >>>>> bandymas.viewpagerexample [ userId:0 | appId:10229 ]
04-01 20:07:31.404    7094-7094/bandymas.viewpagerexample D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
04-01 20:07:31.584    7094-7094/bandymas.viewpagerexample W/ApplicationPackageManager﹕ getCSCPackageItemText()
04-01 20:07:31.594    7094-7094/bandymas.viewpagerexample I/PersonaManager﹕ getPersonaService() name persona_policy
04-01 20:07:31.794    7094-7094/bandymas.viewpagerexample I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:381>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (CL3869936)
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 17.01.11.SPL
    Build Date: 01/17/14 Fri
    Local Branch:
    Remote Branch:
    Local Patches:
    Reconstruct Branch:
04-01 20:07:31.844    7094-7094/bandymas.viewpagerexample D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
04-01 20:07:42.454    7094-7094/bandymas.viewpagerexample W/ApplicationPackageManager﹕ getCSCPackageItemText()
04-01 20:07:42.485    7094-7094/bandymas.viewpagerexample I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onNestedScrollAccepted, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onNestedScrollAccepted
04-01 20:07:42.485    7094-7094/bandymas.viewpagerexample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11347: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onNestedScrollAccepted (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/View;I)V
04-01 20:07:42.485    7094-7094/bandymas.viewpagerexample D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
04-01 20:07:42.485    7094-7094/bandymas.viewpagerexample I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onStopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onStopNestedScroll
04-01 20:07:42.485    7094-7094/bandymas.viewpagerexample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11353: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onStopNestedScroll (Landroid/view/View;)V
04-01 20:07:42.485    7094-7094/bandymas.viewpagerexample D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
04-01 20:07:42.485    7094-7094/bandymas.viewpagerexample I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.stopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setHideOnContentScrollEnabled
04-01 20:07:42.485    7094-7094/bandymas.viewpagerexample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9041: Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout;.stopNestedScroll ()V
04-01 20:07:42.485    7094-7094/bandymas.viewpagerexample D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000e
04-01 20:07:42.495    7094-7094/bandymas.viewpagerexample I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
04-01 20:07:42.495    7094-7094/bandymas.viewpagerexample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 365: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
04-01 20:07:42.495    7094-7094/bandymas.viewpagerexample D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
04-01 20:07:42.495    7094-7094/bandymas.viewpagerexample I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
04-01 20:07:42.495    7094-7094/bandymas.viewpagerexample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 387: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
04-01 20:07:42.495    7094-7094/bandymas.viewpagerexample D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
04-01 20:07:42.525    7094-7094/bandymas.viewpagerexample D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
04-01 20:07:42.525    7094-7094/bandymas.viewpagerexample W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4187fda0)
04-01 20:07:42.525    7094-7094/bandymas.viewpagerexample E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: bandymas.viewpagerexample, PID: 7094
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{bandymas.viewpagerexample/bandymas.viewpagerexample.End}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at bandymas.viewpagerexample.End.addListenerOnButton(End.java:33)
            at bandymas.viewpagerexample.End.onCreate(End.java:23)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**activity_end.xml**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="bandymas.viewpagerexample.End">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Result"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What is line 23 in `End.java`?

Comment: I assume, line 23 is `button.setOnClickListener(...`. Which throws `NullPointerException` when `button` is `null`, which is when `findViewById()` cannot locate the button. Please show your layout.xml

Comment: Create a database and tables as you required and use radio button.

Comment: The crash is caused by attempting to access a checkbox that is null. The `findViewById()` returning null as your layout for the activity does not contain `R.id.checkBox1` etc.

Comment: Can you please provide code of your activity_end layout?

Answer (score 0):

Please Check that there is the `button(R.id.button)` in activity_end.xml.

I guess that the button's id doesn't exist in activity_end.xml.

Comment: There's no button in activity_end.xml. The button is in _fragment3_layout.xml_ and when I press it I want that the results would be displayed in a new activity called _End.java_. Can it be that findViewById() returns a View if it exists in the layout I provided in setContentView(), otherwise it returns null and that's what happening to me? If so, how can I make it find my checkboxes and a button in other fragments?

Comment: @Kaspis245 Then, why did you declare `three checkboxes` and `button` in `End.java`? you mean that there are `three checkboxes` in each `fragment(n)_layout.xml` with last fragment has `button`, and that fragments belong to other Activity (not `End.java`)? finally when you click the button in last fragment and you want to display your results in new Activity called `End.java`?

Comment: That's exactly the situation I have and what I want.

Comment: @Kaspis245 Then, you don't have to declare that checkboxes and button in End.java. Declare that components in each fragment. And when you click the button in last fragment, you should deliver the results using `Intent` to End.java from last fragment.